If-then-else statement with page number as the condition
I want to check the page count of the entire document to implement different commands using an if-then-else statement. I've looked all over SE, but I haven't found a solution that works for me; if I missed a post with the solution, please point me in that direction. Below is an example of what I want to do:
\ifthenelse{page-count = 1}{do something}{do something else}

I've tried using lastpage:
\usepackage{lastpage}

\ifthenelse{\pageref{LastPage}=1}
  {do something}
  {do something else}

but the code only does the something else, even with 1-page documents. I believe \pageref{LastPage} does not give me a numeric value.
I also tried using zref-totpages as in:
\usepackage{zref-totpages}

\ifthenelse{ztotpages=1}
  {do something}
  {do something else}

but this also does the something else, only, even when there is clearly just one page. I've even tried printing the values of \pageref{LastPage} and ztotpages in the document, confirming that "1" prints out. How can I get the total page count in a way that returns a numeric value that can be used in a conditional statement?
PS: I've also tried using \ifnum \else \fi instread of \ifthenelse as well as \equal{}{} for implementing the conditional statements without success.

You can test for \PreviousTotalPages, it contains the number of pages from the previous run:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
2: \ifnumcomp{\PreviousTotalPages}={2}{true}{false}

4: \ifnumcomp{\PreviousTotalPages}={4}{true}{false}

\newpage 
blub
\end{document}


This works if I include it inside the document body. It doesn't if I add it to the preamble (it only does the "something else"). I'm trying to add this code to a cls file. Do you know how I could make it work?

The aux file from the previous run is read only at begin document. Delay your code with \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{...}.

Perfect! Now it works as expected. Thanks!!

Use \PreviousTotalPages to pick up the page count from the previous run.
